# SQL Query Distinct keyword issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, distinct

While executing join query I am getting duplicate data instead of the "distinct" keyword. I dim much more google and gained nothing. The table names are "Event" which holds list of events and the other table is UserEvents which assgins vents to users. On event can be assigned to multiple users. I am using SQL server 2005.

```
Events
eid | ename
-----------------
e1  | Test event1
e2  | test ecent2

UserEvents
id| uid |  eventId
-----------------
1 | u1  |  e1
2 | u1  |  e2
3 | u2  |  e1
```

**Query:**

```
select distinct 
Events.eid, Events.ename,UserVents.uid  
  from
      Events
  inner join
      UserEvents on
      UserEvents.eventID=Events.eid
```

**Output:**

```
eid | ename       | uid
-------------------
e1  | Test event1 | u1
e2  | Test event2 | u2
e1  | test event1 | u1
```

**Issue:**

Here, Event is repeating instead of the distinct key word. It should not repeat the event 'e1".
Kindly help me. How I change the query? Is this an issue in SQL server 2005??
kinly help

Comment: Your output isn't what you really get is it. What values are in the `uid` column? I'd guess the value are different for each row with the same `eid` so your distinct is working.

Comment: @XXXcoder - Any particular reason you downvoted my answer? It gives entirely accurate results for your example data as opposed to the made up ones in your question (your last line is not correct) and explains why your understanding of `DISTINCT` is incorrect.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Your output is my isse. I dont want the event to be repeated. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: Is it a typo that the output has `u2` and `e2` on the same row? Joining on `eid` would not give that result. Also, what is your expected output with the given data.

Comment: @XXXcoder - I did read your question. You asked whether the results you were getting were an "issue in SQL Server 2005". To which the answer is "No" [`DISTINCT` isn't broken](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/a-pragmatic-quick-reference.html) it is returning exactly what it is supposed to. You still haven't explained - given that there are multiple possible `uid` values that could be returned for a particular `Events.eid, Events.ename` which one you want selected.

Comment: You only say what the output should *not* be. It would be much easier to find a solution if you posted the output you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` applies to the whole column list. The whole row needs to be the same to be eliminated.

The results you have put in your question are not complete as you have missed out the `uid` column.

```
WITH Events(eid,ename) AS(
SELECT 'e1' ,'Test event1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'e2' ,'test ecent2')

,UserEvents(id,uid,eventId) AS
(
SELECT 1,'u1' , 'e1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'u1' , 'e2' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'u2' , 'e1'
)
select distinct 
        Events.eid, Events.ename,UserEvents.uid  
        from
        Events
        inner join
        UserEvents on
        UserEvents.eventId=Events.eid
```

Returns

```
eid  ename       uid
---- ----------- ----
e1   Test event1 u1
e1   Test event1 u2
e2   test ecent2 u1
```

None of the rows are the same.

Comment: "None of the rows are the same." Are you crazy? That is the issue. I dont want the e1 repeat.

Comment: @XXXcoder: Martin absolutely right, none of rows are same. That's the way distinct keyword must return- the unique set of ALL selected fields. Your first sample has incorrect result, it must be a typo. Please, read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187(v=sql.80).aspx more carefully. And nothing personal, ok?

Comment: Wrong, I dont want that result. I dont want "e1" to be repeated.

Comment: @XXXcoder - Stop telling us what you don't want and instead explain what you **do** want. Although not that I care my participation in this and any of your future questions is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Please, clarify your question, what result do you want to see. Your first query returned distincted result, you can check it on SE data explorer here
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/115261
From MSDN: DISTINCT
Specifies that only unique rows can appear in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

if the distinct keyword is not working try adding a group by clause.
Your new query should look like:

```
select  
            Events.eid, Events.ename,UserVents.uid  
            from
            Events
            inner join
            UserEvents on
            UserEvents.eventID=Events.eid
group by Events.eid, Events.ename,UserVents.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

> It should not repeat the event 'e1
>
> How I change the query?

This might be what you are looking for:

```
select E.eid, 
       E.ename, 
       E.uid
from (
      select Events.eid, 
             Events.ename,
             UserEvents.uid,
             row_number() over(partition by eid 
                               order by UserEvents.uid) as rn  
      from Events
        inner join UserEvents 
          on UserEvents.eventId=Events.eid
     ) as E
where E.rn = 1
```

Result:

```
eid  ename       uid
---- ----------- ----
e1   Test event1 u1
e2   test ecent2 u1
```

Try it on SE Data: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/115257/

Comment: Since my only reason of being on SE answering questions is to learn I would really appreciate a comment on the down vote so I can give better answers next time.